# Refactoring Java field type altogether with getters and setters in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, field, getter-setter

I have simple task to refactor some field type in Eclipse and was rather surprised there is no built-in function for that. Maybe I am missing something?
I need to change the type of a field and getters/setters should change correspondingly. Is that possible out-of-the-box? Or maybe there is some plugin?

Comment: voted as a tool rec. Despite the goofy close reason listed above

Comment: However, the solution proposed in the above guestion doesn't affect getters/setters as they cannot be treated as direct assignments. What should I do then?

Comment: Hand type your code, like the rest of us :p

Comment: Good tip, mate! That's what I wanted to hear :)